# PyQT: is it possible to register a system shortcut for MyApplication?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'd like to register a system shortcut for my application. For example:

- Shortcut 1: minimize application to
  tray
- Shortcut 2: open my minimized
  application
- Shortcut 3: do some function...

I want to do each without having focus in my application

is it possible?

Comment: So you want global keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: yes. I have some native applications that manage this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to send keys to your app when it doesn't have focus with Qt. You have to handle that at the OS level.  On Windows I use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

> [PyGS](https://github.com/jmatt/pygs) a single purpose wrapper for [QxtGlobalShortcut](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtglobalshortcut.html)

It not's quite PyQT, but it does fit with the framework and designed to solve your problem.